# Extensions found in intellisense but not at compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is REALLY frustrating! I have a common library of code I use across projects. However for some reason my extensions have stopped working in this project. I have used them in plenty of other projects and I have no idea what's stopping them working now! Grr!

Here's an example extension so you can see how they're set up.

```
 public static string ToAlphaNumeric(this string InputString)
 {
        string OutputString = string.Empty;
        OutputString = Regex.Replace(InputString, @"[^a-zA-Z_0-9]+", "-");
        OutputString = Regex.Replace(OutputString, "[_]+", "-");
        OutputString = OutputString.Trim(new char[] { '-' });
        return OutputString;
 }
```

My current project is v4.0 and my code library is 3.5, though I have tried upgrading it to 4.0 but that dosn't fix it. I add a reference to the top of every page because I can't get defining it in the web.config to work.

It is definitely referenced on my page and found in the intellisense. However when I build the project I get an error which says 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToAlphaNumeric'. But it does! Why do I get this error?

I apologise if I've missed any needed info, tried to include everything I can think of.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to add a reference to the assembly of your code library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set both projects to 3.5 - no real answer to this issue..

Comment: when I targeted .NET 4.5 I got the runtime error:
    "Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the   runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information".
And when I ran it targeting NET 2.0 I got the same problem as you.
It works when targeting .NET 3.5.
I'm referencing a 3. party dll which is causing the problem. But it took some time to figure out :-(

Answer (score 3):

The two most likely causes of this error are

- You forgot to add a reference to the project in which the extension is defined
- You forgot to add a using for the namespace where the extension is defined

The easiest way to track down which was is at fault is to remove the extension syntax and do a straight static call.

```
TheNamespace.TheExtensionType.ToAlphaNumeric(myString)
```

Now the compilation will either work or complain that `TheExtensionType` is not available.  If it works then your `using` is incorrect, if it fails then you're missing a reference to the assembly.

Comment: It's neither of those things, the reference is there and the using is definitely there too. Like I say I've used this in other projects and I've got everything set up the same. I downgraded my main project from 4 to 3.5 and they started working again. Lost as to why!

Comment: @Jon it sounds like an issue then between projects targeting different versions of the framework.  I'm not sure why that would cause it though without some other build / warning in the system. Have you tried moving everything to 4.0 and seeing what happened?

Comment: Yeah, essentially when I upgraded the class library to 4.0 everything was 4.0 and I got the error. That's what makes this so strange. The fact that it was in the intellisense seems to indicate that there is no error with the code and yet it won't build!

Comment: @Jon intellisense is an *approximation* of what's legal vs. what's actually legal.  In general intellisense is more permissive than the actual compiler would be.  So just because it shows up in intellisense doesn't mean it will necessarily be legal in the final code.

Comment: remove the extension syntax and do a straight static call is a good workaround for such issue

Answer (score 1):

Beside the obvious answers (no reference\ no using)

When trying to "Rebuild" a solution or a project within a solution, when the solution has project dependency that is incorrect or not full :

Objects appear as known by the intelisence, but in rebuild may fail and leave an error, claiming that they are not recognized.

In this case just, clean solution and "Build" each project by the order of the dependancy, or fix solution project dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

Arrived here by google searching similar symptoms.

I had this issue when someone had updated a project reference to use framework 4.5 but the referencing assembly was still 4.0.

Fixed by updating all assemblies to same version.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar that, the intellisense was not showing any error, nor any build errors but during runtime it will throw method not found exception.

Luckily I checked the warning tab and it had a warning like, click this warning to fix the bindings in the configuration file or it will use default bindings. I clicked it and viola, everything worked.

Visual Studio 2015 - ASP.Net MVC 5 on .Net 4.6.1